# Fake Phone Number

Tags: hardware

Nothing dishonest.  I do not want the world to have my phone number when texting.  Can I use a fake number to text from my laptop or cell phone Android S4. Verizon  I tried textfree but can't make it work no matter what I do.  Thanks For Your Help.No opinions please just suggestions. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly ways to send a text without revealing your actual phone number, as spamming telemarketers have proven (we won't stoop to their level, however).

One way is simply using an app like [Private Text Messaging & Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.coverme.im).

A Google search found [this interesting article](http://smartphones.wonderhowto.com/how-to/anonymous-texting-101-block-your-cell-phone-number-while-sending-text-messages-0139658/).

Another way is to use [Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice). Here is an excerpt from the support page: "You can send and receive text messages using your Google Voice number on the Google Voice website, in the Google Voice app, through your SMS messaging app, or through Hangouts." With Google Voice, you can create and use a totally different phone number right on your device.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

You cannot fake a number from an actual phone using a a network provider. The most you can do is hide your number from being sent, as it is handled by the network, not your phone. But, since you asked about texting, then the following applies:

You can, however fake a number from a text. Ever phone number has its own email address. Usually `phonenumber@networkprovider.com` or something. You can email a device that way, and fake your source phone number - you could even change the phone number to a word or phrase. But, note, it wouldn't be possible to receive any reply from the person you message.

A quick Google search should show various websites that provide a free hidden texting service. I am also in development of a site like this.